# Errors executing certain algorithms in QGIS Processing Toolbox?

Tags: qgis, error, algorithm, ascii

When I execute certain algorithms in Proccesing Toolbox, for example "Convert polygon/line vertices to points" I get the following error:

> Algorithm Convert polygon/line vertices to points starting...
>   shapes_polygons "Convert Polygon/Line Vertices to Points" -SHAPES "C:\Users\8725~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\159c5dd99017473d89a0bd321b8d8c0c\OUTPUTLAYER.shp" -POINTS "C:\Users\8725~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\7d7d0235a7cc4bfb993f52aa3775dfc0\POINTS.shp"
>   'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 23-33: ordinal not in range(128) See log for more details

On the other hand, when I execute the "Extract nodes" algorithm I don't get any problems...

I run on Win 10 Home 64-Bit Greek and QGIS 2.10 Pisa.
Probably the problem has to do with greek letters somewhere in my system. My user account on my pc is in greek.

Comment: Your username is likely to be the problem. Could you create another user with a simple name and try again?

Comment: @Joseph, that is the solution. I created a new user name AND user folder with english characters and the problem was solved! Thank yoyu very much!

Comment: Most welcome, glad you found the solution! I will mark this as a duplicate question as it's pretty much the same as another ;)